# Pass a function result to html in Django

Tags: python, django

While learning Django, I can't figure out one simple thing. May be very obvious to any Django devs. I've read the docs and it seem to have to work.
Here's my code:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'radio/index.html', {'title': 'Radio'})

def function_name():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

```
#index.html

<div>
    <h1>{{ function_name }}</h1>
</div>
```

Yet the result is:

```
<div>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

I must be missing something fundamental but can't find out what it is.

Comment: Looks like you are not actually calling the function. Did you try ```{{ function_name() }}```?

Comment: Did you *pass* a reference to the function to your view? Can you show how you call the `render(..)` function to render the template?

Comment: @SteveBoyd: the Django template engine automatically calls callables if these appear in variable names. In fact calling functions explicitly is not possible in Django templates.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem: Sorry, my mistake, not really a Django user, just a python user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. I am a noob here :D
I've updated the post with full views.py. Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function in the context of your `render(..)` call, like:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'radio/index.html',
        {'title': 'Radio', 'function_name': function_name}
    )

def function_name():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Since otherwise, it is not in the context of the template, and hence you can not render it accordingly.